# Котлин не сконфигурирован

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Не понимаю, в чем проблема есть вот такое вот сообщение после того как добавил котлин в проект

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но все билдится и запускается и еще, это сообщение только в файлах котлина

Не пойму, толи глюк студии толи я что то не так сделал

Правка

А вот еще вылезло такое сообщение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у меня также было..после обновления прошло

Comment: @Cypher обновления чего?

Comment: студии до 3.0..

Comment: плагин глючит. Перезапустить-переустановить-обновится. Любая комбинация из этих трех действий может помочь.

Comment: Писать в саппорт JetBrains или Google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С общем в итоге переустановил студию и все работает